# Download google file to memory in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to work on a function to download a google file straight to memory. It works for downloading it to a file but I want to skip that step and hold the contents in memory. Can someone please lend a few ideas on how to handle the piping into a string or buffer?  Here is my code below

```
function downloadFile(){
  var fileId = "xxxxxx"
  var testStr = ""//was trying to write it to a string
  var dest = fs.createWriteStream(testStr);

  drive.files.export({
     auth: oauth2Client,
     fileId: fileId,
     mimeType: 'text/csv'
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log('Done Dowloading' + testStr);
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Error during download', err);
  })
  .pipe(dest);
  dest.on('finish', function() {
      dest.close((evt)=>{console.log(evt)});  // close() is async, call cb after close completes.
    })
  dest.on('error',function (err) {
    console.log("error in pipe of dest \n" + err)
  })
}
```

I was trying to download it to a string and I couldn't figure out how to make a buffer with a dynamic byte allocation.  To recap it works for passing an actual file into createWritableStream but I want it to go straight to memory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way is to use a module like [`stream-buffers`](https://github.com/samcday/node-stream-buffer) to replace your file stream with:

```
const streamBuffers = require('stream-buffers');
...
let dest = new streamBuffers.WritableStreamBuffer();
```

To access the data:

```
dest.on('finish', () => {
  let data = dest.getContents();
  ...
});
```

Comment: I get an error saying that createWriteStream() is not a constructor.  I'll try looking more into the package though

Comment: @Peter3 sorry, my bad, I fixed my answer :)

Comment: thanks I just found the write syntax on npm.  When I print data out it gives me a buffer that prints out everything into hexadecimal bytes.  Do you have any experience with now converting that back into "english"

Comment: So there is another function the package exposes that I used for this. Thanks so much. 
let data = dest.getContentsAsString();